# CLLocationManager initialization

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

I'm working on a web application that enables users to login, only at specific locations. I'm using CLLocationManager and I initialized and called `startUpdatingLocation` at `AppDelegate -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. My UIWebView is supposed to pull the location at initialization to determine whether user's within the specified locations. However, at the launch of my application, `[locationManager location]` is always null and updates *after* my UIWebView is initialized and displayed therefore already sending an error message to the user.

How do I make my locationManager update its location at initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you've coded the location stuff correctly. What you are missing (but have seen) is that the update most certainly does not happen instantaneously. You need to "gate" the rest of your UI's presentation (i.e. your webview) on the location information becoming available. There are a lot of ways to do this. A common tactic is to present a full-screen "HUD" or veil with some indicator to the user that the app is initializing or locating them (with an activity indicator, too, is always a nice touch.) Behind that (out of sight to the user) you can be waiting for the location result and then kickoff the appropriate UI update, and then drop the veil.

Any of that make sense or give you some ideas? I've done this plenty of times. Synchronizing async activities (like location updates) with real-time UI updates that make sense can be challenging, but isn't impossible. :-)

Comment: Follow up question, how do I tell when locationManager has acquired the location or when it's still updating?

Comment: Perhaps you have not coded your location updates correctly afterall... :-) When you call `startUpdatingLocation`, an asynchronous process is started to do just that. When you created your `CLLocationManager` object, you should set its `delegate` to `self`. Then, you need to implememnt the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods that are called when the location is actually updated (and there is one for if the update fails.) When these delegate methods are called, you then know you have (or don't have, in the case of a failure) updated location info.

Comment: I have set `delegate` to `self` and am using `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` (which currently shows that it's updated after I actually need the location). However, `locationManager:didFailWithError` is never called (or I just don't know when it gets called). Or should I be using another method instead?

Comment: Nope, sounds like you have it right. So, when the app launches, you need to show the user that the app is initializing -- doing something -- and that's it, while you wait for the location update to complete (or fail). At that point, and in those delegate methods that you implement, you can then continue with your UI initialization, e.g. remove the "veil" (or whatever you decide to show the user) and replace it with location-based data or an error or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to account for an initial nil value in your applications UI and wait for the first location update.

### -location

> **Discussion** 
>   The value of this property is nil if no location data has
>   ever been retrieved.
>
> It is a good idea to check the timestamp of the location that is
>   returned. If the receiver is currently gathering location data, but
>   the minimum distance filter is large, the returned location might be
>   relatively old. If it is, you can stop the receiver and start it again
>   to force an update

Also you should check out [Region Monitoring](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) since you would like for you users to only be able to login at specific locations.